# Submit Button enable and disable in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like to create a form with text box and submit button using JavaScript. The button should enable only when i enter a total 10 digit phone number in to text box.

Comment: Have you tried anything to accomplish what you want?

Comment: that's an honourable task, I hope you don't have any problem with it, but if you do, feel free to share your non-working code and I'm sure one of the nice people on SO will attempt to explain what you did wrong. Have a nice day

Answer (score 1):

Very simple solution: https://jsfiddle.net/tkx3dcna/

HTML

```
<input id="phone" type="text">
<button id="btn" disabled>Send</button>
```

JS

```
var btn=document.getElementById("btn");
var phone=document.getElementById("phone");
phone.onkeyup=function(){
    btn.disabled=!(phone.value.length===10);
};
```

Comment: PS: there is `!==` :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, though Madara was right, you should try these things out yourself, no?

```js
var num = document.querySelector("input[type='number']"),
  submit = document.querySelector("input[type='submit']");


num.onkeyup = function(event) {
  var val = this.value + '';
  if (val.length === 10) {
    submit.disabled = false;
  } else {
    submit.disabled = true;
  }
};


// Use below method instead, submit button shows immediately after the numbers are a length of 10
/*
function areYouReady() {
  var val = num.value + '';
  if (val.length === 10) {
    isReady = true;
    submit.disabled = false;
  } else {
    isReady = true;
    submit.disabled = true;
  }
  requestAnimationFrame( areYouReady );
}
areYouReady();
*/
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="number" maxlength="10" required>
  <input type="submit" onsubmit="" disabled="true">
</form>
```

Comment: `requestAnimationFrame( areYouReady );` --- this is terribly inefficient. You better attach a listener to the input keyup events.

Comment: @zerkms read the comments. That was the first thing I did. Run the code with the listener uncommented and you'll understand why I used requestAnimationFrame

Comment: I have no idea how your commented code is relevant to what I suggested. Check the other answer if you're not sure how to deal with keyup.

Comment: @zerkms look at the code, it would listen for an onchange event. But that behaved weird. Did you even run the snippet with the commented code uncommented -_-

Comment: Again, I have no idea how my advice on using `onkeyup` event is relevant to your code with `onchange`. `.onchange` is not a solution either.

Comment: Ahh, keyup event I see, misread. I see, I'll edit the code